# Outsourcing Authentication to OpenID or OAuth for My Web Service

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid

I have a Windows desktop application that gathers and stores metadata about a user's media library.  It's similar in concept to trakt and follw.it, but the data is stored locally on the user's computer in an embedded database (SQLite).

I'd like to add functionality to let users upload their metadata to a server online.  This will let me add new features such as displaying their content on the web and social networking aspects.

So I'm thinking of creating a web service for users to upload and download their media data.  I'm wondering though if it's possible to use OpenID or OAuth so that I can outsource the authentication part.  This is what I'm thinking:

- Desktop app asks the user to authenticate with an OpenID or OAuth provider; user Anthony chooses to use his Twitter account, using his login name RepWeiner.
- Now that Anthony has been verified to be RepWeiner on Twitter, the data uploaded from the desktop app to the server will be identified to be owned by "RepWeiner on Twitter".
- Later, Anthony's hard drive crashes, losing everything in it. He installs the desktop app again in order to download his data from the server.  Again, he logs in using his Twitter account.
- The desktop app downloads all the data belonging to "RepWeiner on Twitter" from the server.

I guess the gist of it is, I want users to identify themselves on the web service, but I also want to avoid making them create yet another login (and I want to avoid having to handle the authentication). Is this idea possible in any way?